# Entity Framework Unable to load the specified metadata

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have recently started to learn EF and stuck at one issue. `Unable to load the specified metadata`. Happens when I configure the Data Source.

I have googled the issue many times but still not able to rectify the issue. 
So far I have gone through the following with no luck?

- Changed ProviderManifestToken="2012" to ProviderManifestToken="2008
- Cleaned the solution / rebuild
- Checked the connectionstring many times to make the model name is correction. Here is the current connection string 
  `<add name="EmployeeDBContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EmployeeModel.csdl|res://*/EmployeeModel.ssdl|res://*/EmployeeModel.msl;
  provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
  provider connection string=&quot;
  data source=PC\SQLEXPRESS2012;
  initial catalog=Sample;
  integrated security=True;
  MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
  App=EntityFramework&quot;
  " providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`
- Gone through this article http://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/troubleshooting-entity-framework-connection-strings-38628
- Deleted the model and recreated.

  - Made sure under .edmx file > Properties > Metadat Artifact Processing - Embed in output assembly is selected.

None of the above has helped me to resolve the issue?

I am running EF version 6, so not sure if I should downgrade to 5?

**UPDATE**

I wanted to add the error happens when I configure the `Entity Data Source Control` on a web form page. When you have to select the Named Connection under Configure Object Context. Hope this helps?

Comment: When do you have the issue? When you are declaring the Code First Entities? When running the migrations? You should add it to you question, because can't be answered with out it

Comment: May be there is some other error in your solution first remove them . This error will be removed automatically when build your solution

Comment: Hi @flechilla I have updated my solution hope it makes more sense now?

Comment: IF you have a database first approach - go to the .edmx file and delete any table from the schema. Then add the same table again and rebuild.

Comment: Hi Marcus I have done as per you advice and still no luck whatsoever? :(